# phpMyAdmin - problems with importing file #1366 - incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have created a database in phpMyAdmin, created a table, where there are 3 columns:

```
ID (INT, PRIMARY, A_I)   
NAME (VARCHAR)   
PRICE (DECIMAL)
```

I have also created a .CSV file to be imported. The structure of the file is as follows:

> ;Kurs Excel 2007;30,00
>
> ;Kurs Word 2007;30,00
>
> ;Kurs Power Point 2007;30,00

There is a semicolon at the beginning of each row as I leave first column empty for auto-incremented ID.

The result I'm getting is:

## 1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

What can be the problem?

Comment: You must set value for ID is NULL, not empty string!

Comment: You can set your own ID values, even if the column is autoincrement, startin g from 1 if empty table, or maxId+1 if some values inside